# Sequential test scenarios for Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, jestjs

I've been starting to use [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) for my React projects, and as a testing library it comes with [Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest).

As part of my React apps, I like to create *integration tests* (as well as unit tests) as I find it useful to be able to check the happy paths in the app are working as expected.  For example: Render (mount) a page using [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme), but only mock out the http calls (using [Sinon](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon)) so that the full React/Redux flow is exercised at once.

Before using `create-react-app`, I've used Mocha for testing, and I found [`mocha-steps`](https://github.com/rprieto/mocha-steps) to be a great extension for integration tests, as it allows tests in a group to be executed in sequence, and handles stopping if a step fails without stopping the entire test run.

Question: **Is there any way to get Jest to behave in a similar way?** Specifically, I'd like to be able to specify a series of tests in a group (such as in a `describe`) and have them execute sequentially in order.

I've been looking through the Jest docs, or for any other libraries that extend it, but I've come up empty. For now, it feels like the only option is to have one large test which makes me sad, and I'd prefer not to swap out Jest for Mocha if I can avoid it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jest` does not currently support flagging specific tests to be run serially (like `ava`'s `test.serial`).

This has been [requested before](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3375) but I don't think they are working on it.

The workaround is for you to identify which test files are to be run concurrently and which ones are to be run serially.

For example, I usually name my unit tests with `*.test.js` and my integration tests with `*.spec.js`.

I can then run my unit tests concurrently.

```
$ jest '(/__tests__/.*\\.test)\\.js$'
```

And I can run my integration tests serially.

```
$ jest '(/__tests__/.*\\.spec)\\.ts$' --runInBand
```

I can combine the two in my `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
    "unit": "jest '(/__tests__/.*\\.test)\\.js$'",
    "integration": "jest '(/__tests__/.*\\.spec)\\.ts$' --runInBand",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run integration"
}
```

Running `npm test` can then run concurrent tests first and then the serial ones next.

Comment: That's an interesting work-around, and might be the best current approach to get something similar to `mocha-steps`. Unfortunately a failure in one of the earlier tests in a group would most likely cause the subsequent tests to also fail, so the "tests failed" count of a run would be misleading - but at least it should work :)  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I've been wanting this feature as well. Especially for end-to-end tests. Until someone makes a PR for that, we'll just have to make do with workarounds.